# Recursively converting files from dos line endings to unix line endings

Tags: file-conversion

I am looking for a command that I could use to run on an entire directory and subdirectory that will convert all line endings from DOS to UNIX.

It should be able to detect if a file is text or binary.

I installed `dos2unix` using macports but it looks that it does miss the recursive option.

Comment: Define how a file is text or binary?

Comment: Text: No ASCII below 32, except for TAB, CR, LF.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try `find . -name "*" -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;`.

---

In case `dos2unix` is not available on your system, you can use the following script (save as `dos2unix` and set as executable):

```
#!/bin/sh

perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/;' $*
```

Comment: Don't run this command in the root of a Git repository or else you'll ruin your repository!

Comment: Also, I had better luck using `perl -pi -e 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\n/;' $*` ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14155400/937084))

Answer (score 1):

Here is one line shell code
`find . -name "*" -type f -exec perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/;' {}  \;`

Comment: One line answers are discouraged. Try adding more detail, or comment on it.

Comment: Works as advertised ! What else to add ? ;-)

Comment: Hm... well it did screw up some png files though. Handle with care